# I can't update my database tables with hibernate?

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate, jpa

I wanted to update my database schema by adding new tables. But hibernate doesn't do anything. My database is still the same every time even I changed the property to create. But it won't change anything. And it's the first time happened. 
I have added annotation and all what is needed and nothing happened.

Comment: Please provide more details. Without more details, it is unlikely anyone will be able to help you. Snippets of code or wiring would be great.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please read [ask] and [mcve] to increase your likelihood of getting an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

First of all make sure that your persistence file has your Entity classes added within the class

`<Class>path.EntityName </Class>`

Secondly, the persistence file should also have the update property set:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
```

However, the above property does not work in the following cases:

- hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" will add a db column that doesn't already exist but will not delete a db column that is removed/no longer in your entity.
- hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" will not modify a db column
  that has already been created.
- hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" won't modify existing table column definitions.

You'll need to backup the table data, drop it and restart your application to get that table's schema back in sync with your entity. Then reload your data. Or you can do it manually through SQL queries on the database tables.

Comment: first of all i would like to thank you for your comment !
But all what you have mentionned in your comment it's already done perfectly in my project ! howerver i wonder it would be because of wildlfy server?

Answer (score 0):

Add hibernate configuration:

```
<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
```

Comment: Please provide your pom and application properties files